# Balck background when HTML5 video loads on chrome and safari

Tags: html, video

Can anyone help me with how to get rid of the black BG from the html5 video ?

It's weird, I ve been searching for help i couldn't get one ? does anyone encountered with this issue at all ?

Issue: I have a page which has html5 video embed-ed and when the page loads it loads BLACK bg first and then the video.
it happens only on chrome, IE and ipad, working fine in FF.

Appreciate ur help, thanks

Answer (score 1):

We faced the same issue, we hide the video and then show it after 100ms playing, it worked for desktop chrome (but may cause problems on Android browsers).